# As user is moving i wanted to plot another mkannotation on his old position which is different than current annotation in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, mkmapview, mkannotation

As user is moving i wanted to plot another mkannotation on his old position which is different than current annotation in objective-c

for which I have written code

```
-(void)plotDotted:(double)latitude :(double)longitude
{

    _busOldAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    [self.sampleMap addAnnotation:_busOldAnnotation];
}
-(void)plotPoint:(double)latitude :(double)longitude 
{
    _busAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    [self.sampleMap addAnnotation:_busAnnotation]; 
}
```

Annotation Delegate

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *Identifier = @"driverView";


        MKAnnotationView* myAnnotation = [self.sampleMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:Identifier];

        if (myAnnotation == nil)
        {
            myAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
            //myAnnotation.enabled = YES;
        }


    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_latituDouble, _longitudeDouble);

    if (coordinate.latitude == _latituDouble && coordinate.longitude == _longitudeDouble)
    {
        myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bus_icon.png"];

    }
    else if (_busOldAnnotation)
    {
        myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_dot.png"];
    }


    return myAnnotation;
}

Called Functions

                                    //1. Remove
                                    [self removeAnnotation];

                                    //3. Add new
                                    [self plotPoint:latitudeDouble :longitudeDouble];

                                    //2. Add Old
                                    [self plotDotted:_latituDouble :_longitudeDouble];

                                    //4. Assign that coordinate to global
                                    _latituDouble = latitudeDouble;
                                    _longitudeDouble = longitudeDouble;

                                    [self.sampleMap reloadInputViews];
```

Everything is working fine that , user is moving on my map ,
Removing previous location, 
but not able to add blue_dot image after that user is moving

Comment: ok i am waiting

Comment: Make another  MKAnnotationView object and use that  for showing the blue dot

Comment: how to differentiate MKAnnotationView for different MKPointAnnotation ?

Comment: use the below answer and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use this and see if it works

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation

{

 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_latituDouble, _longitudeDouble);

if (coordinate.latitude == _latituDouble && coordinate.longitude == _longitudeDouble)
{
        static NSString *Identifier1 = @"driverView";

    MKAnnotationView* myAnnotation = [self.sampleMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:Identifier1];

    if (myAnnotation == nil)
    {
        myAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
        //myAnnotation.enabled = YES;

    }
    myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bus_icon.png"];
    return myAnnotation;


}
else if (_busOldAnnotation)
{
        static NSString *Identifier2 = @"driverView2";

    MKAnnotationView* myAnnotation = [self.sampleMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:Identifier2];

    if (myAnnotation == nil)
    {
        myAnnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
        //myAnnotation.enabled = YES;
    }
    myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_dot.png"];
    return myAnnotation;


}

 return nil;
}
```

Comment: i made some changes now see if it works and if not i want the whole code to see what is the problem

Comment: yes i have tried your suggestion that is different identifier for different annotation but not working. please refer my below edits and code